# I'm stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

I am coding a database and while doing so I got stuck into an infinite
 loop.

```
#!/bin/usr/python3  import os, sys import math

try:
    project_file = open('work_good.txt', 'w+')
    text = project_file.read() 

except FileNotFoundError as error:
    text = ('File not found')
    print (text)
    project_file.close()

with open('work_good.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_names = []    
    my_names = f.readlines()

def Zone():
    #Introduction to the database
    print ('WELCOME TO THE DATABASE', file=project_file)
    print (23*'=', file=project_file)


def Username():
    #Ask for users username
    usr_name = input ('What do you want your current username to be?: ').strip().capitalize()
    print ('Your username is: {}'.format(usr_name), file=project_file)
    return usr_name
         def Change_Username():
    #Information for the user to change their username
    change_usr = input ('Would you like to change your username? (y/n): ').strip().lower()

    if change_usr == 'y':
        status = input ('Enter your new username: ').strip()
        print ('Username is changing...', file=project_file)
        print ('Your new username is: {}'.format(status), file=project_file)

    elif change_usr == 'n':
        pass

    else:
        print ('No such command was given!', file=project_file)
     def Password():
    set_password = input ('What will be your password?: ').strip()
    password = ('Your password is: {}'.format(set_password))
    print (password, file=project_file)

def Password_Change():
    change_password = input('Do you want to change your password? (y/n): ').strip().lower()

    if change_password == 'y':
        password1 = input ('What will your new passsword be: ')
        password2 = ('Your new password is: {}'.format(password1))
        print (password2, file=project_file)

    elif change_password == 'n':
        print ('Your password remains the same'.upper(), file=project_file)

    else:
        print ('No such command has been given!', file=project_file)

Zone()

counter = 0

while counter <= 3:
    usr_name = []
    usr_name = Username()
    my_names.append(usr_name)
    print (usr_name, file=project_file)

Change_Username() Password() Password_Change()
```

I think at the final line at the while loop that's where the problem
could lie.

I have tried adding if and else statement but that has failed.

I have also tried adding a break, pass, and a continue, but that has
 failed as well.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: `counter` starts at 0. You loop while `counter <= 3`. You never update `counter`. So your loop goes on forever.

Comment: Well I don't see how you set your `while` condition to `False` by modifying `counter`

Answer (score 1):

Your counter is `0` and you never update it ever again, so it's always smaller then `3`, for ever. You should increase it after every run, add another line inside the `while` loop:

```
counter += 1 # This increment the variable by 1 on each loop
```

And when it reaches `4` your loop will end

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @OferSadan

Comment: Happy to help, next time try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that will probably help you answer it yourself or it will make sure you'll get better answers. Don't forget to upvote ;)